# How do I import multiple unformatted data files into SAS while skipping multiple lines for each file?

Tags: sas

I am trying to import multiple unformatted data files in a single folder into a SAS dataset using a `'*.xle'` wildcard while skipping the first 47 lines of each file.  SAS will use the `'firstobs=48'` for the first file but will ignore for each subsequent file and begin reading at line 1. I have set up the code using the `eov=0` as suggested on multiple other Stackoverflow threads, but it still does not seem to work. Any help is much appreciated. Please see my code below:

```
data test;
     infile "*.xle" eov=eov firstobs=48;
     input @;
     if eov then input;
     input Date $ 19-28 / Time $ 19-26 // Data 18-24 / Temp 18-22 //;
     eov=0;
run;
```

Comment: Which other resources did you consult? May you please edit your question accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close you need to input 47 times when you start a new file EOV=1.

Alternatively you could use FILEVAR and FIRSTOBS would work for each file but that would require generating a list of filenames to use to drive the data step.  Six vs. half dozen so to speak.

```
filename FT15F001 '.\a.xle';
parmcards;
a line 1
a line 2
a line 3
a line 4
;;;;
filename FT15F001 '.\b.xle';
parmcards;
b line 1
b line 2
b line 3
b line 4
;;;;
filename FT15F001 '.\c.xle';
parmcards;
c line 1
c line 2
c line 3
c line 4
;;;;


data test;
   infile "*.xle" eov=eov firstobs=3 length=l;
   input @;
   if eov then do;
      do _n_ = 1 to 2; input; end;
      eov=0;
      end;
   input line $varying40. l; 
   list;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the variable created by the EOV= option, but I have found it easier to just use FILENAME= instead and then use LAG() function to detect when a new file starts.

To skip 48 lines you could execute multiple INPUT statements or add multiple / characters to one INPUT statement.

```
data test;
  length fname $256 ;
  infile "*.xle" filename=fname ;
  input @;
  if fname ne lag(fname) then do;
     input %sysfunc(repeat(/,48-1));
  end;
  input Date $ 19-28 / Time $ 19-26 // Data 18-24 / Temp 18-22 //;
run;
```

Note that if any of the files is actually shorter than expected then you will need to be more careful in both the skipping step and the reading step. Otherwise when you read multiples lines in one INPUT statement you could read past the end of one file and start reading lines from the next file.

It might be better to get the list of files first and use that with the FILEVAR= option to drive the process. Then INFILE executes separately for each file and you can use the FIRSTOBS= option.  You will then need to add a loop to read and output the observations from the text file(s). This way each iteration of the data step will process one whole file.

```
data files;
  infile "ls *.xle" pipe truncover ;
  input filename $256.;
run;

data test;
  set files ;
  fname=filename ;
  infile dummy filevar=fname firstobs=48 end=eof;
  do while (not eof);
    input Date $ 19-28 / Time $ 19-26 // Data 18-24 / Temp 18-22 //;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

But again reading multiple lines in one INPUT statement is dangerous and you should change the code that reads the lines to read them one by one and check that you have not read past the end of the file yet.  Remember that SAS will stop the whole data step if INPUT statement (or SET statement) reads past the end of the input stream.